# Javascript stopwatch not reliably stopping

Tags: javascript

I have a stopwatch controlled by pressing space which looks something like this:

```js
let startTime;
let stopTime;
let timerStatus = 0;
let timePassed;
let interval;

window.onkeyup = function(event) {
 if(event.keyCode == 32) {
  if(timerStatus == 0) {
   start();
   display();
  } else if(timerStatus == 2) {
   timerStatus = 0;
  }
 }
}

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
 if(event.keyCode == 32) {
  if(timerStatus == 1) {
   stop();
  } else if(timerStatus == 0) {
   $("#time").html("0.00");
  }
 }
}
  
function start() {
 let d = new Date();
 startTime = d.getTime();
 timerStatus = 1;
}

function stop() {
 let d = new Date();
 stopTime = d.getTime();
 clearInterval(interval);
 timerStatus = 2;

}

function display() {
 interval = setInterval(function() {
  let now = Date.now();
  timePassed = now - startTime;

  let seconds = Math.floor(timePassed / 1000);
  let minutes = Math.floor(timePassed / 60000);
  let milliseconds = timePassed % 1000;
  //getting rid of third decimal place
  milliseconds = milliseconds.toString().slice(0, -1);
  parseFloat(milliseconds);
  console.log(milliseconds);
  
  let time = minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;

   if(milliseconds < 10) milliseconds = "0" + milliseconds; 
   if(milliseconds < 1) milliseconds = "0" + milliseconds;
   if(minutes < 1) {
    time = seconds + "." + milliseconds;
   }

  $("#time").html(time);

 }, 10);
}
```

```html
<h1 id='time'>0.00</h1>
```

This works just fine, apart from the fact that sometimes when pressing space to stop the stopwatch, it will instead stop and then immediately start the stopwatch again. Often after this happens once, you then can't ever stop the stopwatch until the page is reloaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: On first glance, it looks like the issue is probably that `onkeyup`, you're calling `start`.. wonder if you could refactor so that all of the logic was `onkeydown`? doesn't look like there's a reason to prefer one over the other

Comment: @wmp224 is right. You stop the timer when the key is *pressed* (`keydown`), but and start the timer when the key is *released* (`keyup`).

Comment: right - depending on how quickly the spacebar is pressed and released it's possible that the status won't have already been incremented

Comment: That makes sense to me, but it is quite important that `start` activates on `keyup`. I'm quite an amateur when it comes to JavaScript, but would swapping the `timerStatus == 0` and `timerStatus == 2` if statements force the latter to run first, fixing the issue? If not, is there another solution?